# Efficiency in word counting

Tags: performance, sorting, tree, quicksort, cpu-word

I've been assigned the task of developing a simple text analyzer, that receives lines as input and counts word frequency, to then print the words ordered by number of occurence, and, within the same frequencies, alphabetically. I wanted to make it as time and space efficient as possible, and am trying to figure out what data structure would be the best, allied to which sorting algorithm.

For now, I had a version of quicksort in mind, but that would mean that my words would have to be already placed in an array, after being counted. A static array would right away make time complexity O(n) for the search operations while processing the input - so I was thinking of taking advantage of another structure such as a balanced binary tree to do the processing, then turning it into an array.

Am I thinking correctly, or would turning a tree into an array harm my efficiency? Any suggestion?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Mafalda, you could use insertion-sort with quick-sort , for example .
Quicksort might be the best approach.

You might want to check this link [why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice](http://why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)

Comment: I can't open that link, but I do understand how quicksort works better generally when put to practice, and also how to use it with insertion-sort. The only problem I'm facing with using that algorithm is that I'd need to put the words received as input into an array and access them to increment their count everytime they show up in the input, and those accesses alone would make me have a O(n) time performance before I got to the sorting part... I'm looking at some tree-like options

Comment: [why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3/why-is-quicksort-better-than-other-sorting-algorithms-in-practice)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your programming language of choice is relatively efficient then using a letter tree (not a binary tree - the fanout should be the size of the character set) populated from a FSM to store the counts would likely be the lowest cost solution.